# Substitue the Cell value in Excell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am just trying to substitute the value of `D1` cell `"08"` with the value of `B2` Cell `01`.

The value of `C2` must be `T-00-0000-0100`.
But The specified formulae seems not working as expected.Thank you!!!

Formulae:

```
=IF(B1="01", SUBSTITUTE(D1, "08", B1), D1)
```

OR

```
 =IF(B1="01", CONCATENATE(LEFT(D1, FIND("08", D1) - 1), B1, RIGHT(D1, LEN(D1) - FIND("08", D1) - 2)), D1)
```

[image]

Comment: try removing the curly brackets? not sure you need them for what you're trying to do here

Comment: You're referencing `B1` while your value is in `B2`. (Note that this would replace any number of instances `08` appears in the string)